# bokeh timeseries plot off by 4 hours

Tags: python, datetime, plot, bokeh

I am having a problem where my datetime points plotted in bokeh are off / shifted by 4 hours. I am running bokeh 0.12.4, Python 2.7.12, Windows 7.

The same problem was reported on [bokeh github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4056), but says there it should be resolved. There is also an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675041/bokeh-time-series-plot-annotation-is-off-by-1-hour) about being off by 1h, but the solution posted there does not seem to apply on Windows. **Does anyone know how to resolve this?**

My example converts two strings to datetime objects, and then attempts to plot them in bokeh. I am using strings, because I eventually plan to extract this data from an SQLite database, and the datetime library because I already use that it my main code (would rather not introduce numpy just for this).

My example attempts to plot data at 08:00 and 15:00, but they instead come out shifted 4 h ahead; 12:00 and 19:00, respectively.

```
import datetime as dt
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

def plotTheData(xvals, yvals, filename="datetime.html", title="boom!"):
    output_file(filename, title=title)
    p = figure(width=800, height=500, x_axis_type="datetime")
    p.circle(xvals, yvals, size=6)
    show(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datetimes = [
        dt.datetime.strptime("2017-03-30 15:00:05","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        dt.datetime.strptime("2017-03-30 08:00:05","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        ]
    doorstates = [0,1]
    plotTheData(datetimes,doorstates)
    for r in zip(datetimes, doorstates):
        print r
        print r[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), r[1]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(datetimes at 08:00 and 15:00, as expected)
(datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 15, 0, 5), 0)
2017-03-30 15:00:05 0
(datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 8, 0, 5), 1)
2017-03-30 08:00:05 1
```

**bokeh plot** (points shown shifted ahead by 4h, at 12:00 and 19:00)
[image: bokeh plot off by 4h]

Comment: Do you live (run your computer) in a timezone which is utc -+ 4h?

Comment: @renzop - nope. My PC is set at: "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

Comment: I tried it out and i am in amsterdam time zone... the timeshift of the points is equivalent to the difference to utc (keep daylight saving time in mind)  but setting the timezone on your datetime objects does not affect the plots.